# Using Jersey Test Framework in Scala

Tags: scala, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use the Jersey test framework along with specs2 to test an HTTP client in Scala.  Here's what I have so far:

```
package com.mypackage

import java.net.URL
import javax.ws.rs.{GET, Path}
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.{TestProperties, JerseyTest}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

// This class provides an HTTP server for testing.
@Path("/")
class MockServer extends JerseyTest {

  @GET
  @Path("ok")
  def getOk = "OK"

  override def configure = {
    forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0") // Choose first available port.
    new ResourceConfig(getClass)
  }

  def getUrl(relativePath: String) = new URL(getBaseUri.toURL, relativePath)
}

// This class contains the tests.
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestHTTPAdapter extends Specification {

  val server = new MockServer

  step {
    server.setUp()
    success
  }

  "HTTPAdapter" should {
    "GET text" in {
      // HTTPAdapter is the HTTP client being tested.
      // Create a new one with a 5 second timeout.
      val httpAdapter = new HTTPAdapter(5)

      // Request data
      val result = httpAdapter.get(server.getUrl("ok"))

      // Verify response
      result.code.code mustEqual 200
      result.bodyString mustEqual "OK"
    }
  }

  step {
    server.tearDown()
    success
  }

}
```

When I run the test, I get an exception:

```
[info] TestHTTPAdapter
[info] ! step error
[error]  NoSuchMethodError: : javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;  (ApplicationHandler.java:304)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:141)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:82)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:66)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:130)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
[error] org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)
[error] com.mypackage.TestHTTPAdapter$$anonfun$1.apply(TestHTTPAdapter.scala:32)
[error] com.mypackage.TestHTTPAdapter$$anonfun$1.apply(TestHTTPAdapter.scala:31)
```

Why isn't this working?  Am I missing a dependency?  In my SBT file, the only Jersey reference is `"org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers" % "jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2" % "2.12" % Test`.

I'd love to get this working using the Jersey test framework, but I'm open to other frameworks if someone can recommend a better option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that one of my project's dependencies was using an old 1.x version of jersey-core.  I added an exclusion to libraryDependencies in build.sbt: `("otherProjectGroupId" % "otherProjectArtifactId" % "otherProjectVersion").exclude("com.sun.jersey", "jersey-core")` Everything works now.